# ios 8 uitableview stuck/hang/freeze when scrolling to the end of table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I really need helps from you. I'm trying to load some data (about 50 records) to `UITableView`. But it got frozen/hang while scrolling to the end of the tableview. I did try to log which row is displaying. When I scroll down, the log show the row 1... 49 is display then it starts over with row 42.

This is the .h file:

```
@interface VDevicesViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSString* access_token;
    NSMutableArray* data;
    NSMutableArray* deviceNotGoodData;
    NSArray* _deviceTypeList;
    NSArray* _thumnailArray;
    DAPagesContainer* pageContainter;
    UITableView* tableAllDevices;
    UITableView* tableNotGoodDevices;

    int currentPage;
    UIView * footerView;
    UIActivityIndicatorView* indicator;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;

-(void)refresh;
@end
```

this is the .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 32, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    deviceNotGoodData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pageContainter = [[DAPagesContainer alloc] init];
    [pageContainter setPageIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up_arrow_gray"]];
    [pageContainter setTopBarBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:24.0f/255.0f green:177.0f/255.0f blue:214.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    pageContainter.pageItemsTitleColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [pageContainter willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    pageContainter.view.frame = self.myView.bounds;
    pageContainter.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    CGFloat width = self.myView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.myView.frame.size.height - 50;
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    UIViewController* allDeviceContoler = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    tableAllDevices = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableAllDevices.delegate = self;
    tableAllDevices.dataSource = self;
    tableAllDevices.tag = 0;

    NSString* allDeviceTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"All Devices(%@)", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:KEY_DEVICES_USED]];
    allDeviceContoler.title = allDeviceTitle;
    [allDeviceContoler.view addSubview:tableAllDevices];

    UIViewController *notGoodDevicesControler = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    tableNotGoodDevices = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableNotGoodDevices.delegate = self;
    tableNotGoodDevices.dataSource = self;
    tableNotGoodDevices.tag = 1;

    NSString* uncompliantDevices = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"With Issues(%@)", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:KEY_DEVICES_UNCOMPLIANT]];
    notGoodDevicesControler.title = uncompliantDevices;
    [notGoodDevicesControler.view addSubview:tableNotGoodDevices];

    [self.myView addSubview:pageContainter.view];
    [pageContainter didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    pageContainter.viewControllers = @[allDeviceContoler, notGoodDevicesControler];
    currentPage = 1;
    access_token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:TOKEN_ACCESS_KEY];
    _deviceTypeList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"desktop", @"laptop", @"phone", @"tablet", @"server", @"router", @"switch", @"vm", nil];

    _thumnailArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"device_desktop_small", @"device_laptop_small", @"phone", @"tablet", @"device_server_small", @"router", @"switch", @"device_vm_small", nil];

    [self GetDevices:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentPage]];
    indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width/2.0, 40, 37, 37)];
    [indicator startAnimating];

    [self.myView addSubview:indicator];
}

#pragma mark - TableViewDelegate
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView.tag == 0) {
        return [data count];
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 1)
        return [deviceNotGoodData count];
    return 0;
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString* cellIdentitifier = @"TableCell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentitifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentitifier];

    }

    NSArray* flexData;
    if (tableView.tag == 0) {
        flexData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:data];
    }
    else
        flexData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:deviceNotGoodData];


    if (flexData.count > 0) {
        if (indexPath.row < ([flexData count])) {
            // add data here
            NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
            VDeviceObject * deviceObject = [flexData objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
            cell.textLabel.text = deviceObject.hostname;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = deviceObject.username;
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180.0f/255.0f green:180.0f/255.0f blue:180.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

            if ([deviceObject.numberOfIssues intValue] > 0) {
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247.0f/255.0f green:247.0f/255.0f blue:247.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
            }

            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_thumnailArray objectAtIndex:[deviceObject.deviceType intValue]]];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ViewDetail" sender:indexPath];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 65;
}
-(void)GetDevices:(NSNumber*)page {
    if (access_token == nil || [access_token isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return;
    }
    NSError* error;
    NSData * devicesData = [VTabBarViewController sendSyncGetRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?access_token=%@&limit=%@&GroupBy=issues&page=%@", GEARS_API_GET_DEVICES, access_token, @"50", page] errorCode:error];

    NSString* errorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:devicesData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* stringCode = @"Requested page number exceeds limit";
    if ([errorString rangeOfString:stringCode].location != NSNotFound) {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray* list = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:devicesData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    for (int i = 0 ; i<[list count]; ++i) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [list objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* hostName = [dict objectForKey:@"hostname"];
        NSString *machine_type = [dict objectForKey:KEY_MACHINE_TYPE];
        NSNumber* numberIssues = [dict objectForKey:KEY_TOTAL_ISSUE];
        NSDictionary *userinfo = [dict objectForKey:KEY_USER_INFO];
        NSString* username = [userinfo objectForKey:KEY_USER_NAME];
        NSString* hwid = [dict objectForKey:KEY_HWID];
        VDeviceObject *object = [[VDeviceObject alloc] init];
        object.username = username;
        object.deviceType = [self deviceType:machine_type];
        object.numberOfIssues = numberIssues;
        object.hostname = hostName;
        object.hardwareId = hwid;

        [data addObject:object];
        if ([object.numberOfIssues intValue] > 0) {
            [deviceNotGoodData addObject:object];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"On page: %d", currentPage);
    //[tableAllDevices reloadData];
    //[tableNotGoodDevices reloadData];
}
```

This is the gif image to demonstrate the problem I've got (I did try to reduce the size but its quality is so bad)
http://s934.photobucket.com/user/quocvinh_2009/media/TableView%20Bug.gif.html

Thank you...

Update: I try to add 'UITableView' by storyboard, connect with the 'IBOutlet', it works. So maybe I did something wrong with the table :(

Comment: That's everything in your .m?

Comment: Can you include your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` code? This information is not sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: these are all my 'delegate' functions. I'll post the function I use to get data for the 'UITableView'. I debug and the data for the table looks fine. The function 'refresh' in the .h file I haven't implemented it yet, so I do not post it here.

Comment: try to set delaysTouch property of scrollview in table view like this : AnimatedScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = AnimatedScrollView.delaysContentTouches;

Comment: hm, I don't get what you mean. What's that for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for helping me.
The problem properly is because of the open source that I use for this project.
Here is the reference https://github.com/daria-kopaliani/DAPagesContainer/issues/9 for anyone who need

Answer (score 0):

The data is displayed for the first 41 lines, so I assume that the deliegates are okay.

The problem rises at the 42nd line. You will probably display 7 or 8 rows at the time. So the issues occur while displaying the 49 or 50th row. Which according to your specs do not exists. Nevertheless the UITableView is trying to fetch that row.

I advise checking the table count:

```
NSLog(@"Rows %d",[tablename count]);
```

And check the UITableView datasource length correct:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableArray count];
}
```

Comment: I checked the data source of the 'UITableView', it's fine. I'll try to re-implement again step by step :(

Comment: It's weird, I try with 'UITableView' created with storyboard, it's fine, however, with the UITableView created programmatically, it fails.